# how to use google api library oauth2? I have id token and access token

Tags: go, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-signin

How do I authorize access to the backend(with go google libary) given that ive authenticated the user from the front end? Front end Auth, I have `access_token` or `id_token`.

- Is there a way to convert `id_token` to an `access token`?
- Is there a way to use `id_token` to run `calendar.NewService`?
- Is there a way to use `access_token` to run `calendar.NewService`?

## my setup

In the extension, I done both:

- From GCP creds oauth2 "chrome app" i can get the "access token".
- from GCP creds oauth2 "web app", i can get the "id token".

In the backend, using go google api library for [calendar](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/calendar/v3)

```
config := &oauth2.Config{...}
// ...
token, err := config.Exchange(ctx, ...)
calendarService, err := calendar.NewService(ctx, option.WithTokenSource(config.TokenSource(ctx, token)))
res, err := calService.Events.List("myemail@gmail.com").Do()
```

I have no idea how to use my `id_token` or `access_token` to use this lib. So far i can do curl requests with the access_token, but that doesnt use this library. is there a way with this google library?

#### Attempts

- Ive read in [cross identity](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/cross-client-identity), that so long as you point to the same client ID in the same project youre good to go. but i keep getting, `token expired or not found`
- i hear id_token is just jwt. so i tried, but i cant get the types correct, so cant even run it.

> ```
> jwt, err := google.JWTConfigFromJSON(g.key, gmail.GmailReadonlyScope)     
> jwt.Subject = "myname@gmail.com" //impersonate user   
> service, err := calendar.NewService(ctx, option.WithHTTPClient(jwt.Client(ctx)))
> ```

- tried with oauth2 key.json

> ```
> serviceAccountKey, err := ioutil.ReadFile("oauth2_webapp.json")  
> conf, err := google.ConfigFromJSON(serviceAccountKey, calendar.CalendarReadonlyScope) 
> token, err := conf.Exchange(ctx,"code") // code seems like another method 
> calendarService, err := calendar.NewService(ctx,
> option.WithTokenSource(config.TokenSource(ctx, token))) 
> res, err := calService.Events.List("myemail@gmail.com").Do()
> ```

"code" shouldnt matter, since i do not want to auth the user via browser link. at this point The user should assume already authenticated from front end. but this doesnt work either.

Comment: You have to be aware of the fact that access token usually expire after 60 minutes, consider setting up [offline access](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#offline). More general, your authentication needs to follow one of the flows authorized by Google. First estimate which is your [scenario](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) and then read the documentation for the respective Auth protocol, e.g. [OAuth 2.0 for Client-side Web Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow).

Comment: thanks for the tip. but thats not what im looking for. im looking to use go api library. i cant figure out how to use it given access token.

Comment: I [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63454292/calling-google-drive-api-from-nodejs-backend-with-authorisation-from-front-end) node.js implementaiton related to your case?

Comment: If you have a valid access token, what prevents you from using it with the [standard procedure](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/go) for go?

Comment: the original method i tried only gave me the accesstoken. using chrome identity. having only access token is not enough. the full token(access, refresh, expiry, and type). so i found another way to get auth code instead realizing "code" was auth code only later. their docs suck. wish we could edit and improve it.

Answer (score 2):

sorry the docs dont have examples. Yeah i tried variations, and finally got it.

id_token is useless.

prior to access token, i had an authCode. I wish in their docs,  they said authcode instead of code. i simply passed the auth code from front end to back end. since i am new to this, remove any html encoding. ie(%2f => /). that was also one reason i couldnt get it.

below works:

```
authCode := "4/3AGEkPVEN9O**70ish char***G0uOPYtQWkUSc" 
// authcode was html encoded which the conf.Exchange needed a decoded version.
saKey, err := ioutil.ReadFile("oauth2_webapp.json")  
conf, err := google.ConfigFromJSON(saKey, calendar.CalendarReadonlyScope) 
token, err := conf.Exchange(ctx,authCode)
```